# How to get user input into a for loop and make the program loop until user enters quit

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

How do I get user input into a for loop and make the program loop until user enters quit?

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("what is your full name?" );
Name = scan.nextLine();
String newString = Name.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println("please enter " + newString.length() + " numbers and the total will be calculated");

if (newString.length() == 3) {
    for(int count = 1; count <= newString.length(); count++)
        System.out.println( "Number " + count + ":" + );
    Num1 = scan.nextInt();
    Num2 = scan.nextInt();
    Num3 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("total is " + (Num1 + Num2 + Num3));
}
```

Comment: wrap you code into while(true) loop and call break when user type quit

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop try this :

```
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        if (input.equals("quit")){
            flag = false;
        } else {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
```